# wscript: Path to .vbs script not found

Tags: vbscript, filepath, wsh

I am working on getting this batch command to call  a .vbs script on our local share folder. There are no restriction to this folder for anyone. when running the script I get this error:

> Windows Script Host
>
> Can not find script file "\bh-miworks-srv2\PrintDrivers\Printers\Benton Harbor\BH Dockside.vbs".

the code is: `wscript "\\bh-miworks-srv2\PrintDrivers\Printers\Benton Harbor\BH Dockside.vbs"`

To me it doesn't get any simpler that that.
I figure its something simple I am missing but I just don't see it.
If anyone has run into this issue before and knows how to fix it,any direction would be appreciated.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use `dir` command instead of `wscript`?

Comment: That server has a share called PrintDrivers?

Comment: Using dir insted of wscript:
"Volume in drive \\bh-miworks-srv2\PrintDrivers is Data2"
"Volume Serial Number is 924F-3AF9"

"Directory of \\bh-miworks-srv2\PrintDrivers\Printers\Benton Harbor
File Not Found"

I need BH Dockside.vbs

Comment: I want to use this script to be able to install 8+ printers depending on what the client needs.

Comment: It seems like a permissions issue to me. Are you running the script with the same credentials you are browsing to the share with?

Comment: I've tried both normal user and run as admin. I have administrative rights on this laptop and the folder on the network dose not have any restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this:

```
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strRemoteShare = "\\bh-miworks-srv2\PrintDrivers\Printers\Benton Harbor" 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "H:", strRemoteShare, False
```

and then start the vbs from H:\BH Dockside.vbs

Comment: Still no luck, "Can not find script file H:\BH Dockside.vbs"  thanks for the suggestion, I will keep trying.